# redirect not working with .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu-14.04

I have this in my htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
Deny from all
#RewriteRule (.*) http://google.com  [R=301,L]
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from 89.32.93.99
RewriteRule index.php$ /otherfolder [R=301,L]
```

I am trying to redirect all the requests to a new folder but for some reason the above does not work.

I have also tried

```
Redirect 301 / /otherfolder
```

but that just added other folder again and again to my domain like this

```
mydomain.com/otherfolder/otherfolder/.....
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your rules like this:

```
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from 89.32.93.99

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /otherfolder [NC,R=301,L]
```

`^(index\.php)?$` will match either `/` or `/index.php` in URL.